# Vertical accordion on multiple CSS3 elements

Tags: css

I create a navigation menu with an accordion-like transition, it's made with CSS3. I'm pretty happy with it, it works great.
Here a live version of the code i made: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/EJoxr

I would like to improve it by adding a new feature: i would like to popup out the article of the div i clicked on but also the previous div.

I mean, if i click on the 4th div named 'Contact Us' i would like to display ALL the articles. Click on the 2th display only the 1st and the 2nd one.

Is it possible to do this with CSS3 ?

*HTML* :

```
<div class="container">
    <section class="ac-container">
        <div>
            <input id="ac-1" name="accordion-1" type="checkbox" />
            <label for="ac-1">About us</label>
            <article class="ac-small">
                <p>Well, the way they make shows is, they make one show. That show's called a pilot. Then they show that show to the people who make shows, and on the strength of that one show they decide if they're going to make more shows.</p>
            </article>
        </div>
        <div>
            <input id="ac-2" name="accordion-1" type="checkbox" />
            <label for="ac-2">How we work</label>
            <article class="ac-medium">
                <p>Like you, I used to think the world was this great place where everybody lived by the same standards I did, then some kid with a nail showed me I was living in his world, a world where chaos rules not order, a world where righteousness is not rewarded. That's Cesar's world, and if you're not willing to play by his rules, then you're gonna have to pay the price. </p>
            </article>
        </div>
        <div>
            <input id="ac-3" name="accordion-1" type="checkbox" />
            <label for="ac-3">References</label>
            <article class="ac-large">
                <p>You think water moves fast? You should see ice. It moves like it has a mind. Like it knows it killed the world once and got a taste for murder. After the avalanche, it took us a week to climb out. Now, I don't know exactly when we turned on each other, but I know that seven of us survived the slide... and only five made it out. Now we took an oath, that I'm breaking now. We said we'd say it was the snow that killed the other two, but it wasn't. Nature is lethal but it doesn't hold a candle to man. </p>
            </article>
        </div>
        <div>
            <input id="ac-4" name="accordion-1" type="checkbox" />
            <label for="ac-4">Contact us</label>
            <article class="ac-large">
                <p>You see? It's curious. Ted did figure it out - time travel. And when we get back, we gonna tell everyone. How it's possible, how it's done, what the dangers are. But then why fifty years in the future when the spacecraft encounters a black hole does the computer call it an 'unknown entry event'? Why don't they know? If they don't know, that means we never told anyone. And if we never told anyone it means we never made it back. Hence we die down here. Just as a matter of deductive logic. </p>
            </article>
        </div>
    </section>
</div>
```

*CSS*:

```
div {
  display: block;
  width: 25%;
  float:left;
}
.ac-container{
    width: 900px;
    margin: 10px auto 30px auto;
    text-align: left;
}
.ac-container label{
    font-family: 'BebasNeueRegular', 'Arial Narrow', Arial, sans-serif;
    padding: 5px 20px;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 20;
    display: block;
    height: 30px;
    cursor: pointer;
    color: #777;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px rgba(255,255,255,0.8);
    line-height: 33px;
    font-size: 19px;
    background: #ffffff;
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #ffffff 1%, #eaeaea 100%);
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(1%,#ffffff), color-stop(100%,#eaeaea));
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #ffffff 1%,#eaeaea 100%);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #ffffff 1%,#eaeaea 100%);
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #ffffff 1%,#eaeaea 100%);
    background: linear-gradient(top, #ffffff 1%,#eaeaea 100%);
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#ffffff', endColorstr='#eaeaea',GradientType=0 );
    box-shadow: 
        0px 0px 0px 1px rgba(155,155,155,0.3), 
        1px 0px 0px 0px rgba(255,255,255,0.9) inset, 
        0px 2px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
}
.ac-container label:hover{
    background: #fff;
}
.ac-container input:checked + label,
.ac-container input:checked + label:hover{
    background: #c6e1ec;
    color: #3d7489;
    text-shadow: 0px 1px 1px rgba(255,255,255, 0.6);
    box-shadow: 
        0px 0px 0px 1px rgba(155,155,155,0.3), 
        0px 2px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
}
.ac-container label:hover:after,
.ac-container input:checked + label:hover:after{
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    width: 24px;
    height: 24px;
    right: 13px;
    top: 7px;
    background: transparent url(../images/arrow_down.png) no-repeat center center;  
}
.ac-container input:checked + label:hover:after{
    background-image: url(../images/arrow_up.png);
}
.ac-container input{
    display: none;
}
.ac-container article{
    background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
    margin-top: -1px;
    overflow: hidden;
    height: 0px;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 10;
    -webkit-transition: height 0.3s ease-in-out, box-shadow 0.6s linear;
    -moz-transition: height 0.3s ease-in-out, box-shadow 0.6s linear;
    -o-transition: height 0.3s ease-in-out, box-shadow 0.6s linear;
    -ms-transition: height 0.3s ease-in-out, box-shadow 0.6s linear;
    transition: height 0.3s ease-in-out, box-shadow 0.6s linear;
}
.ac-container article p{
    font-style: italic;
    color: #777;
    line-height: 23px;
    font-size: 14px;
    padding: 20px;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px rgba(255,255,255,0.8);
}

.ac-container input:checked ~ article.ac-small{
    height: 140px;
}
.ac-container input:checked ~ article.ac-medium{
    height: 180px;
}
.ac-container input:checked ~ article.ac-large{
    height: 230px;
}
```

NB: I can use SASS if needed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer for how you have it implemented is: No, you cannot accomplish this with just CSS

However, if you changed your markup and display, you might be able to target things the way you would like, though you may have to change your styles quite a bit. Regardless, right now you have:

```
div-1
  input-1
  article-1
div-2
  input-2
  article-2
...
```

You cannot target the first article when the second input is checked because you cannot traverse out of the `div-2` and, even if you could, you cannot traverse from `div-2` to `div-1`.

With that said, if you really wanted to try, you could pull out the divs, reverse the markup & display order (and style them inversely, using floats or text-direction). Then, you could do:

```
input-4
article-4
input-3
article-3
....
```

Which you could style using using floats or text-direction to still visibly show 1,2,3,4. Because the markup is 4,3,2,1 you can, in theory, target the lower numbers if the higher are checked, with something like:

```
input:checked ~ article {/*show*/}
```

With this rule, if the fourth input (which, again, can be displayed on the right eventhough it is first in the markup) is checked it will show all the articles. Also, if 3 is checked (and 4 is not), 3,2,1 would show, etc.

Comment: Thx, now the question is: will i fix the display with the new config :)